# Java The import com.google.common.io.Files cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am working on building and running an android application in Eclipse. I have successfully installed the Android kit, along with the google api. I went here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/auth and followed the sample code.

However both com.google.common.io.Files and com.google.common.base.Preconditions are giving me an error.

any idea what I need to do next to get this issue resolved please?

Comment: Are you using any external jar file?

Comment: I went to this link http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup and followed the eclipse section.. right-click on project etc

Comment: add guava jar to the classpath

Comment: can you give me the link where I can find that jar file please? thanks

Comment: Thanks RC found the link, added it and all works..

Answer (score 3):

To Solve this issue,

I went to this link : https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release14, downloaded the guava jar file. Then I added it to the classpath and compiled successfully..

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a maven project you can add the dependency to the `pom.xml` as below.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>r05</version>
</dependency>
```

The above dependency would solve the problem.
Please refer the maven repository for the latest versions [Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/r05)